# C++ pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I know that in C++, the name of an array is just the pointer to the first element of the array. For example:

```
int foo[5];
```

=> **foo** is a pointer of type int, and it points to the first element in the array, which is a[0]

But then, we have this:

```
int (*foo)[5]
```

Here, **foo** is a pointer to an array of type. So is **foo** a pointer to a pointer (of type int)?

Comment: No, it's a pointer to an array. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: This has to be a dupe, right?

Comment: @CarlNorum, Oh, let me count the ways.

Comment: Arrays are pointers with a bit more overhead like array size and padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in C++, the name of an array is just the pointer to the first element of the array

That's not correct: a name of an array can be *converted* to a corresponding pointer type "for free", but it is definitely *not* a pointer. The easiest way you can tell is by comparing sizes of a pointer and of an array:

```
int foo[5];
int *ptr;
cout << sizeof(foo) << endl;
cout << sizeof(ptr) << endl;
```

Your second example is a pointer to an array of `int`s of size 5.

```
cout << sizeof(foo) << endl;
cout << sizeof(*foo) << endl;
```

In a 32-bit environment [this prints](http://ideone.com/p48h4) `4` and `20`, as expected.

Comment: So in the second case, if it's a pointer to an array, what is the type of the pointer? Is it just "array"?

Comment: @Chin Its type is "a pointer to an array of integers of size five" (pretty long name, huh?).

Comment: @Chin Take a look at [this link to ideone](http://ideone.com/p48h4) that illustrates the point from my last comment.

Comment: Thanks. In my second example, I just want to know from a memory-diagram perspective whether it is a pointer to a pointer. But since it's not a pointer in the first example... I think I get the idea

Answer (score 5):

This is an array of five ints:

```
int a[5];
```

This is a pointer to an array of five ints:

```
int (*p)[5] = &a;
```

This is a pointer to an int:

```
int * q = a;  // same as &a[0]
```